# How to de-normalize specific columns in a data set in neural networks

Tags: r

I am new to R programming.

I have normalized selected three variable columns in my data set using following code;

```
normalize <- function(x) {
  return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
norm_exchangenew <- as.data.frame(lapply(exchangenew_random[3:6], normalize))
```

Similarly applied the following to de-normalize the same columns.

```
denormalize <- function(x, min, max) { 
  return( (max - min)*x + min )
}

Tommorow_pred <- denormalize(predicted_Tommorow, Tommorow_min, Tommorow_max)
Tommorow_pred
```

But the results table contains all the values as **"NA"**. How do I de-normalize the previously selected variable columns(integer)? please note that there are both string and integer values in the columns.

The data i used can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JS3_uyCMHc-PA6OikbnE-nodP0u05uhd?usp=sharing)

Any suggestions will be very much helpful.

Comment: You cannot de-normalize string values using min and max values. Do you use same min and max value for all columns?

Comment: No not the same. It is for each column

Comment: You have to store the min and max values somewhere before de-normalizing the data.